# Know when Android app is in background

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to create events for when my app goes to background.
I'm looking at the onPause() and onDestroy() methods but these are also called as I navigate through different activities and call finish().

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: once u called finish() ur actvity will not exist

Comment: which type of event you want to crete? mention exact requirment

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you Call `OnDestroy()` Your Activity is removed or finished. For checking in Background check when your `OnPause()` is called.

For more information on that [Activity Life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

create one class which extends `Application`

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

  public boolean status=false;

}
```

then use this variable in all Activities.

in onPause() `myApp.status=false;`

in onResume() `myApp.status=true;`

Answer (score -1):

If you go by checking this from your activity then your application will always be on foreground, my suggestion is to make a separate service which keeps on checking for the current top application.

```
private String getCurrentTopActivity() {

        ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager
                .getRunningTasks(1);
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
        return ar.topActivity.getClassName().toString();
    }
```

If this is equal to your packagename then your application is in front ground else it is in background